# double& (not passing by reference) C++

Tags: c++, reference, double, declaration

```
typedef double real8;

typedef real8 Real_t;

Real_t& x(int y);
```

What is `Real_t&` ?? I've only seen a datatype followed by "&" to indicate pass by reference. 
But this is in declaration line. What does this mean ?

Comment: This **is** a declaration line. It declares `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means that the function returns a reference to a `Real_t` which is actually a `double`.  The `Real_t` is a `real8` which is a `double` if you resolve all the typedefs.

**You should be careful here.  If the result being passed by reference isn't retrieved from a scope that exists pasts the end of the function, then you'll have a dangling reference.**

For example:

```
int& foo() {
    int x = 8;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int y = foo();
}
```

The variable, `y`, in main ends up referring to a variable which has been destroyed as it went out of scope when `foo()` returned, so using it is **undefined behavior**.  If `x` had been retrieved from a singleton or something that lives outside the scope of the function `foo()`, then it would still exist though and this would be fine.

People sometimes return references to initialize static globals in a deterministic way between compilation units, so you might see this used with statics like:

```
MyClass& MyStaticVar() {
    static MyClass instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Which is also okay, because the static lives for the duration of the program after initialized.

Answer (score 7):

It means `x` is a  function that returns a reference to a `Real_t`.

An example of returning by reference is for data access in classes. For example, [std::vector::at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) returns a reference to an element of the vector.

For a free function to safely return a reference, there must be something non-obvious going on inside the function to ensure that a dangling reference isn't returned.